# How do you set an HTTPS redirect for ALB in an Elastic Beanstalk configuration file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to make Elastic Beanstalk to auto-create an HTTPS redirect rule in the Application Load Balancer when the EB environment is created from a config file. I can see that Amazon has a yaml example but it doesn't reflect the format of my configuration file: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config

I would like to configure the redirect in the load balancer not in my reverse proxy (Nginx).

This is what I have in the config right now. There is nothing for HTTP:80 - which EB creates by default I guess.

```
OptionSettings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
    SSLCertificateArns: <my cert arn>
    DefaultProcess: default
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Rules: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The "yaml" files provided by the AWS,  `alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config` and `alb-http-to-https-redirection.config` are to be placed (after your modifications if needed; HTTPs requires SSL certificate) in your [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) folder.

They are actual EB config files, but look like yaml CloudFormation files. So in your zip package would have files `.ebextensions/alb-http-to-https-redirection-full.config` and/or `alb-http-to-https-redirection.config` along side your application.